# Regex date replace

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have dates like the following (note trailing 'T')

```
2011-11-07T15:24:28
2011-11-07T
```

With regex i need to extract just the date part so both will look like this

```
20111107
20111107
```

.net

Have a webservice that is returning a date like 2011-11-07T15:24:28, but on some occasions it returns date with no time but still with the trailing T. This causes .net's cdate function to bail out.

Comment: in which language? you might not need a regexp

Comment: What is the language? Maybe there is a date object, that is able to handle this.

Comment: This is an ISO 8601 datetime. .NET is able to parse this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want JavaScript:

http://jsfiddle.net/3edLJ/1/

```
var message = "One is 2011-11-07T15:24:28 and the other is 2011-11-07T (it had a trailing t)"

var regex = /(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)T(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)?/g;

function extract(s) {
    return s.replace(regex, "$1$2$3");
}

alert(extract(message));
```

This regex properly drops the time part.

Answer (score 1):

Is this so trivial?

```
/(\d{4})-(\d\d)-(\d\d)/
```

Use backreferences $1$2$3 as your result.

Or is there something you are not telling us?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my suggestion. The Regex is:

```
(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T
```

The replacement:

```
$1$2$3
```